# How to move InnoDB table to another drive?

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona

I have MySQL running on SSDs, SSDs that I'm about to run out of space on. My webhost overcharges for SSDs and the majority of the data in MySQL is "archived" data (i.e. data that isn't actively used). I have larger HDDs that can hold this data. As such, I want to be able to move specific InnoDB tables from the SSDs to the HDDs.

One solution I've thought about and researched is moving the individual .ibd files (I have innodb_file_per_table enabled) for the specific tables in question to the HDDs and then symlink. However, researching this, it looks like that is a bad idea for InnoDB.

I've also seen that since 5.6, MySQL supports the DATA DIRECTORY command:

> To create a new InnoDB file-per-table tablespace in a specific
>   location outside the MySQL data directory, use the DATA DIRECTORY =
>   absolute_path_to_directory clause of the CREATE TABLE statement.
>
> Plan the location in advance, because you cannot use the DATA
>   DIRECTORY clause with the ALTER TABLE statement. The directory you
>   specify could be on another storage device with particular performance
>   or capacity characteristics, such as a fast SSD or a high-capacity
>   HDD.

The problem is, it looks like this is only supported for *new* tables. I want to do it for existing tables. Any tips on how? I'm running Percona MySQL, if it helps.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Here is what I tried, but I'm getting a syntax error:

`CREATE TABLE abc_2 LIKE abc ENGINE=InnoDB DATA DIRECTORY='/xxx/mysql/archive/'`

Comment: I take it mysqldump would not be helpful here?

Comment: Well, I'm trying something like that. I am trying to create a new table using the LIKE command and DATA DIRECTORY (then copy the data over) but it won't work.

Comment: Maybe if you told us *exactly what you tried* and the *specific error message* yu got we might be able to advise. (you can't just move the files with innodb, even though this is possible with myISAM as long as you create a link to the new location).

Comment: Added an update showing the command that I tried

Comment: I guess I was asking: why not use mysqldump directly?

Comment: @barrycarter I want to copy the structure of the table over before I can copy the data over. How would I use mysqldump with DATA DIRECTORY command?

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but mysqldump should give you the table structure too.

Comment: @barrycarter I'm not an expert, so maybe I am the one missing something, but I need to use the DATA DIRECTORY command to place the InnoDB data file on a drive different than my MySQL drive. How would I do that with mysqldump?

Comment: Oh, I get it now. You want to have databases in two different directories, /var/lib/mysql/ and an alternate directory of your choosing, without putting symlinks into /var/lib/mysql. I'm assuming you can't stop MySQL, tweak /etc/my.cnf, restart it, and continue from there? In other words, you need to have both locations live at the same time?

Comment: @barrycarter Rick James hit it on the head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `CREATE ... LIKE ... DATA DIRECTORY ...` is a combination that is not supported.

Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to get the current definition.  Edit it to add `DATA DIRECTORY` and `INDEX_DIRECTORY`.  Then use the edited text to create the new table.

Then `INSERT INTO new_tbl SELECT * FROM real_tbl;` and shuffle the names:  `RENAME TABLE real_tbl TO old_tbl, new_tbl TO real_tbl;`.

Verify the results and finally `DROP old_tbl`;

Comment: That was quick response.  Glad to hear that it works.  I gather you already had `innodb_file_per_table=ON`.  I was not sure about needing to specify the `INDEX DIRECTORY` too, since both are in the same `.ibd`.

Comment: Yes, I already had innodb_file_per_table=ON. I didn't add INDEX DIRECTORY, just added DATA DIRECTORY to the output from the SHOW   command.

Comment: Also, looks like INDEX DIRECTORY only applies to MyISAM, so it won't even work with InnoDB. Just need DATA DIRECTORY as that moves the .ibd which holds data and index.

Comment: Note that one needs to also rename foreign key constraints for the new table.

Comment: `INSERT INTO new_tbl SELECT * FROM real_tbl;` seems super-slow for very large tables. Is there a smart way to make this faster (InnoDB)?

Comment: To move InnoDB tablespace without rebuild the entire table:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-moving-data-files-offline.html

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this problem myself, and eventually found a more elegant solution than 'create new - copy - switch': detaching, moving and re-importing the underlying tablespace files. This is much more efficient on large and/or heavily indexed tables as MySQL does not have to redo work it has already done.

In short, it comes down to the following steps:

```
FLUSH TABLES `table_name` FOR EXPORT;
```

While keeping the connection open, move the tablespace files in a shell:

```
$ mv /var/lib/mysql/database_name/table_name.{ibd,cfg} ~
```

Now back in MySQL release the lock, drop the table, re-create it with the correct `DATA DIRECTORY` and discard its tablespace:

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name`;
DROP TABLE `table_name`;
CREATE TABLE `table_name` /* ... */ DATA DIRECTORY='/path/to/desired/location';
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

Now copy the moved tablespace files to the desired location:

```
$ cp -a ~/table_name.{ibd,cfg} /path/to/desired/location
```

And import them:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

---

More background and motivation for why 'create new - copy - switch' is inefficient can be found in a blogpost I wrote on this topic: https://www.moxio.com/blog/28/moving-individual-mysql-tables-on-disk.

Comment: Your blog post was almost helpful, but I kept getting a schema error that led me to this open bug - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76142. I don't know how you were able to get your setup working.

Comment: ERROR 1808 (HY000): Schema mismatch (Table location flags do not match. The source table does not use a DATA DIRECTORY but the destination table does.)

Comment: I have tried this with MariaDB 10.6.4, but got `ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 37 'Data structure corruption' from /var/lib/mysql/mydb/MyTable.ibd`

Comment: Perhaps also moving `*.frm` was my mistake?